# Equivalent infinitesimal in limits

Tags: limits, radicals

In the limit question we have to calculate

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+ } \dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x+3x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}}$$

Can I use the method of equivalent infinitesimal to replace the functions?

Like we replace $\sin x $ with $x$ when $x \rightarrow 0 $.

In the question removing the cube roots doesn't remove the indeterminacy. So, can I remove the cube roots?

I want to know the deep maths behind this method. I only use this method to solve limits fast but I don't know whether this is applicable at all places?

Comment: Hint. For $x\to 0^+$, $\frac{\sqrt[3]{x+3x^2}-\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^4}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+3x}-1}{x}$. Now $(1+ax)^b\sim 1+\dots$ ?

Comment: I know It can be solved by many other ways, but I want to know where and actually how we apply the method of equivalent infinitesimals in order to solve limits faster?

Comment: My hint is just about "equivalent infinitesimals" because $(1+ax)^b-1\sim abx$, i.e. the infinitesimal $(1+ax)^b-1$ is equivalent to the infinitesimal $abx$. Therefore the limit is $ab=3\cdot\frac{1}{3}=1$

Comment: BTW $(1+ax)^b-1\sim abx$ is in the list of list of the "most popular equivalent infinitesimals" given here: https://math.fel.cvut.cz/en/mt/txtb/5/txe3bb5l.htm

Comment: Infinitesimals in the sense of non-stadard analysis?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the expression in your problem a little further:

\begin{align*}
\frac{(x+3x^2)^{1/3}-x^{1/3}}{x^{4/3}}=\frac{x^{1/3}\Big((1+3x)^{1/3}-1\Big)}{x^{4/3}}=\frac{(1+3x)^{1/3}-1}{x}
\end{align*}

Then you can use the infinitesimal equivalency that Robert Z mentioned in his comment above: $(1+3x)^{1/3}\stackrel{\cdot}{\sim}1+x$